# Нужна помощь с RedM сервером по RDR2 RP

Tags: c#, lua

У меня перестал запускаться сервер по RDR2 RP.При включение сразу же выкл.сервер,в консоли выдает такую ошибку, жалуясь на скрипт, после его удаление и возвращение предыдущего скрипта. Сервер так же не вкл.

```
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for vorp_adminmenu
Symbol file LoadedFromMemory is not a mono symbol file
[script:vorp_adminmen] Instantiated instance of script vorpadminmenu_sv.BanManager.
[script:vorp_adminmen] Instantiated instance of script vorpadminmenu_sv.LoadUsersInfo.
[script:vorp_adminmen] vorp_adminmenu: Language En.json loaded!
[script:vorp_adminmen] Instantiated instance of script vorpadminmenu_sv.LoadConfig.
[script:vorp_adminmen] Instantiated instance of script vorpadminmenu_sv.PlayerBanned.
[script:vorp_adminmen] Instantiated instance of script vorpadminmenu_sv.TriggersDatabase.
[script:vorp_adminmen] Instantiated instance of script vorpadminmenu_sv.TriggersServer.
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource vorp_adminmenu
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for vorp_weaponstore
[script:vorp_adminmen] Unhandled task exception:
[script:vorp_adminmen] Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'CitizenFX.Core.ExportSet' does not contain a definition for 'execute'
[script:vorp_adminmen] at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,string,string[],System.Action`1<object>)
[script:vorp_adminmen] at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3] (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3) [0x0012c] in <3e501f8d5238405b81a46e43e9571825>:0
[script:vorp_adminmen] at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Action`5[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,System.Object,System.String,System.String[],System.Action`1[System.Object]].invoke_void_T1_T2_T3_T4_T5(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,string,string[],System.Action`1<object>)
[script:vorp_adminmen] at vorpadminmenu_sv.BanManager.LoadBannedsFromDB () [0x00087] in <a2885e26dd05427b9beb770fcaf7fbcd>:0
Symbol file LoadedFromMemory is not a mono symbol file
[script:vorp_weaponst] vorp_weaponstore: Language En.json loaded!
[script:vorp_weaponst] Instantiated instance of script vorpweaponstore_sv.LoadConfig.
[script:vorp_weaponst] Instantiated instance of script vorpweaponstore_sv.weaponstore_init_sv.
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource vorp_weaponstore
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for vorp_banks
[ script:vorp_banks] Instantiated instance of script VORP_BankServer.Database.
[6nvorp_banks: Language Es.json loaded!
[ script:vorp_banks] Interaction
[ script:vorp_banks] InsuficientMoneyInstatnTrasference
[ script:vorp_banks] InsuficientMoneyTrasference
[ script:vorp_banks] Instantiated instance of script VORP_BankServer.LoadConfig.
Vorp Core: retrieveUserBankInfo function callback registered!
Vorp Core: searchUsers function callback registered!
[ script:vorp_banks] Instantiated instance of script VORP_BankServer.Server.
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource vorp_banks
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for vorp_barbershops
[script:vorp_barbersh] Instantiated instance of script vorp_barbershops_sv.barbershops_sv.
[script:vorp_barbersh] vorp_barbershops: Language En.json loaded!
[script:vorp_barbersh] Instantiated instance of script vorp_barbershops_sv.LoadConfig.
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource vorp_barbershops
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for vorp_housing
[ script:vorp_housing] Instantiated instance of script vorphousing_sv.HouseInventory.
[ script:vorp_housing] vorp_housing: Language En.json loaded!
[ script:vorp_housing] Instantiated instance of script vorphousing_sv.LoadConfig.
Vorp Core: getRooms function callback registered!
Vorp Core: getHouses function callback registered!
[ script:vorp_housing] Instantiated instance of script vorphousing_sv.vorp_housing_sv_init.
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource vorp_housing
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for VORP_Fishing
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: fishbait registered!
[ script:VORP_Fishing] Instantiated instance of script vorp_fishing_sv.FishingEvents.
[6nVORP_Fishing: Language En.json loaded!
[ script:VORP_Fishing] Instantiated instance of script vorp_fishing_sv.LoadConfig.
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource VORP_Fishing
[ citizen-server-impl] Couldn't find resource weathersync.
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource uiprompt
[ citizen-server-impl] Couldn't find resource spooner.
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource redm_blips
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for vorp_hunting
Vorp Core: vorp_hunting:getjob function callback registered!
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource vorp_hunting
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource progressBars
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource no_dot
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for kcrp_boats
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource kcrp_boats
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource ipl
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource freecam
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource RedM_Ragdoll
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for Bulgar_doorlocks_vorp
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource Bulgar_doorlocks_vorp
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for baitshop
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource baitshop
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource at_anims
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for at_ped
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource at_ped
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource interactions
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for vorp_ml_policejob
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource vorp_ml_policejob
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for poke_medicjob
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource poke_medicjob
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for wcrp_interaction
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: CONSUMABLE_CIGARETTE_BOX registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: CONSUMABLE_HAIR_GREASE registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: cigar registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: notebook registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: pocket_watch registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: book registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: pipe registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: fan registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: chewingtobacco registered!

[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource wcrp_interaction
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for fred_metabolism
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource fred_metabolism
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for Redm_Stores
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource Redm_Stores
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for syn_ranch
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource syn_ranch
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for green_canteen
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource green_canteen
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for poke_rpchat
Vorp Core: getGroupReport function callback registered!
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource poke_rpchat
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for redemrp_me
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource redemrp_me
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for GoldPaning
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource GoldPaning
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource redemrp_notification
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for rgn_miner
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource rgn_miner
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for syn_crafting
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: campfire registered!
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource syn_crafting
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for dzp_poker
[ script:dzp_poker] Error parsing script @dzp_poker/server.lua in resource dzp_poker: @dzp_poker/server.lua:5: ']' expected near 'g'
[ c-scripting-core] Failed to load script server.lua.
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource dzp_poker
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for gum_farming
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Agarita_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Alaskan_Ginseng_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: American_Ginseng_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Bay_Bolete_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Bitter_Weed_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Bulrush_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Black_Berry_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Black_Currant_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Blood_Flower_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Burdock_Root_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Cardinal_Flower_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Chanterelles_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Choc_Daisy_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Creekplum_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Creeking_Thyme_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Crows_Garlic_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Desert_Sage_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: English_Mace_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Evergreen_Huckleberry_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Golden_Currant_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Hummingbird_Sage_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Indian_Tobbaco_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Milk_Weed_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Oleander_Sage_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Oregano_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Parasol_Mushroom_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Prairie_Poppy_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Rams_Head_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Red_Raspberry_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Red_Sage_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Texas_Bonnet_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Violet_Snowdrop_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Wild_Carrot_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Wild_Feverfew_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Wild_Mint_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Wild_Rhubarb_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Wintergreen_Berry_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Wisteria_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Yarrow_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Agarita_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Alaskan_Ginseng_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: American_Ginseng_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Bay_Bolete_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Bitter_Weed_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Bulrush_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Black_Berry_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Black_Currant_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Blood_Flower_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Burdock_Root_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Cardinal_Flower_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Chanterelles_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Choc_Daisy_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Creekplum_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Creeking_Thyme_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Crows_Garlic_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Desert_Sage_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: English_Mace_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Evergreen_Huckleberry_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Golden_Currant_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Hummingbird_Sage_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Indian_Tobbaco_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Milk_Weed_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Oleander_Sage_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Oregano_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Parasol_Mushroom_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Prairie_Poppy_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Rams_Head_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Red_Raspberry_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Red_Sage_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Texas_Bonnet_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Violet_Snowdrop_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Wild_Carrot_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Wild_Feverfew_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Wild_Mint_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Wild_Rhubarb_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Wintergreen_Berry_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Wisteria_Seed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: Yarrow_Seed registered!
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource gum_farming
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for gum_ecology
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource gum_ecology
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource bc_camping
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for saltychat
[ script:saltychat] Instantiated instance of script SaltyServer.VoiceManager.
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource saltychat
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for Ciudad_Farm
[ script:Ciudad_Farm] Config petrole load
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource Ciudad_Farm
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for bandana
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource bandana
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for syn_search
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource syn_search
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for vorp_moonshiner
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource vorp_moonshiner
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for lto_drugs_effect
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: weed registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: appleCrumbMoonshine registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: wildCiderMoonshine registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: tropicalPunchMoonshine registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: tonic registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: consumable_brandy registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: CONSUMABLE_WHISKEY registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: beer registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: mushs registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: pill registered!
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: cocaine registered!
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource lto_drugs_effect
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource handsup
[ citizen-server-impl] Couldn't find resource juan_train.
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource bulgar_max_cores
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for vorp_weaponsv2-main
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource vorp_weaponsv2-main
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for lto_headbucket
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: headbucket registered!
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource lto_headbucket
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource lto_mapanimation
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource lto_teleport
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for moonshine_job
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource moonshine_job
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for syn_dice
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource syn_dice
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource syn_minigame
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for syn_society
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource syn_society
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for syn_stores
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource syn_stores
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for vorp_postman
[ script:vorp_postman] vorp_postman: Language Es.json loaded!
[ script:vorp_postman] Instantiated instance of script vorp_postman_sv.LoadConfig.
[ script:vorp_postman] Instantiated instance of script vorp_postman_sv.vorp_postman_sv_init.
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource vorp_postman
[ c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for Vorp_walkanim-main
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource Vorp_walkanim-main
[ citizen-server-impl] Couldn't find resource webadmin.
[ svadhesive] Authenticating server license key...
cfx> [ svadhesive] Server license key authentication succeeded. Welcome!
[ script:mapmanager] Started map redm-map-one
[ citizen-server-impl] Started resource redm-map-one
vorp_inventory: Function callback of item: ammo_bullet_revolver registered!
[script:vorp_inventor] Unhandled exception: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'CitizenFX.Core.ExportSet' does not contain a definition for 'execute'
[script:vorp_inventor] at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,string,System.Action`1<object>)
[script:vorp_inventor] at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2] (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) [0x0011e] in <3e501f8d5238405b81a46e43e9571825>:0
[script:vorp_inventor] at vorpinventory_sv.ItemDatabase.LoadDatabase () [0x000e8] in <ab2857a7dc494152a971a5ef8f030b9a>:0
[script:vorp_inventor] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
[script:vorp_inventor] at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (System.Object state) [0x00007] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
[script:vorp_inventor] at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00071] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
[script:vorp_inventor] at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
[script:vorp_inventor] at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00021] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
[script:vorp_inventor] at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00074] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
[script:vorp_inventor] at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
Unhandled exception in Mono script environment: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'CitizenFX.Core.ExportSet' does not contain a definition for 'execute'
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,string,System.Action`1<object>)
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2] (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) [0x0011e] in <3e501f8d5238405b81a46e43e9571825>:0
at vorpinventory_sv.ItemDatabase.LoadDatabase () [0x000e8] in <ab2857a7dc494152a971a5ef8f030b9a>:0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (System.Object state) [0x00007] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00071] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00021] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00074] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,string,System.Action`1<object>)
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2] (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) [0x0011e] in <3e501f8d5238405b81a46e43e9571825>:0
at vorpinventory_sv.ItemDatabase.LoadDatabase () [0x000e8] in <ab2857a7dc494152a971a5ef8f030b9a>:0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (System.Object state) [0x00007] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00071] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00021] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00074] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in <4fffd39960df419684f9b9cb5ce46688>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас отсутствует база данных, или же неправильные данные MYSQL логин и пароль)

Comment: а вернее он не может найти item либо таблицу либо какие то предметы )

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).